# my loop cut is not going round my object and there are all quads

Tags: modeling

[image]

my loop cut is not going around my object, and I had checked that there are all quads

Comment: have you removed doubles? maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I think it is stopping where you don't have faces. Look in solid view and see if there is a face at the end of the new loopcut.

Comment: Check if the edge where it stops is connected to the rest of the mesh